# SpeechSynthesis in Big Sur

Tags: c, gcc, text-to-speech, speech

I'm running MacOS 11.6.1 on an M1 Mac.  Trying to compile a simple text-to-speech program using GCC in a Terminal window.

Make file is: gcc vocabTest.c -o vocab

It compiles, but won't link.  Have tried g++.  Have tried -arch x86_64.  Keep getting error:

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_CFStringCreateWithCString", referenced from:  etc

Am I missing libraries?

Any help greatly appreciated.  I'm strictly an amateur at programming.  Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>
// #include "SpeechSynthesis.h"

int main(void)
{
    char text[120] = "Hello, World";        /* lines, S/E, chars */
    SpeechChannel chan;
    CFStringRef aString;
    
    aString = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, text, kCFStringEncodingMacRoman);
    
    printf("text = %s\n", text);
    
    SpeakCFString(chan, aString, NULL);
    
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: *Am I missing libraries?* - you are most definitely missing the linker options which are pointing which libraries to link.

Comment: A web search produced: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542942-cfstringcreatewithcstring It looks like that is part of `swift`

Answer (score 1):

My thanks to those who responded.  It helped set me on the path to find an answer.  I, indeed, needed to link libraries.  Here is the final, working MakeFile and Code.

```
gcc vocabTest.c -o vocab -framework Carbon

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>

int main(void)
{
    char text[120] = "Hello, World";        /* lines, S/E, chars */
    SpeechChannel chan;
    CFStringRef aString;
    OSErr theErr = noErr;
    
    theErr = NewSpeechChannel(NULL, &chan);
    
    aString = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, text, kCFStringEncodingMacRoman);
    
    SpeakCFString(chan, aString, NULL);
    
    while (SpeechBusySystemWide());
    
    return(0);
}
```